# Why PTRACE_GETREGS does not work on arm so file in MoMo(an android emulator) Player on windows?

Tags: c, linux, arm, shared-libraries, ptrace

I want to attach arm so file to running apk. 
This is my code.

```
#include <pthread.h>

#define GAME_PACKAGE_NAME "com.example.user.myapplication"

pid_t  pid;
struct pt_regs regs;
int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    pid = find_pid_of(GAME_PACKAGE_NAME);
    if (ptrace(PTRACE_GETREGS, pid, NULL, &regs) < 0) {
        DEBUG_PRINT("ptrace_getregs: Can not get register values");
        return -1;
    }
    if (ptrace(PTRACE_SETREGS, pid, NULL, &regs) < 0) {
        DEBUG_PRINT("ptrace_setregs: Can not set register values");
        return -1;
    }
    if (ptrace(PTRACE_CONT, pid, NULL, 0) < 0) {
        DEBUG_PRINT("ptrace_cont");
        return -1;
    }
    if (ptrace(PTRACE_DETACH, pid, NULL, 0) < 0) {
        DEBUG_PRINT("ptrace_detach");
        return -1;
    }
}
```

When I build above code as "x86" and install it on emulator it works well.

When I build this code as "arm", 
`ptrace(PTRACE_GETREGS, pid, NULL, &regs)` line works but content of `regs` is empty. So `ptrace(PTRACE_SETREGS, pid, NULL, &regs)` line error occurs.

I don't understand why PTRACE_GETREGS does not work on arm.

Comment: If you read the [man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/ptrace.2.html), it says _PTRACE_GETREGS and PTRACE_GETFPREGS are not present on all architectures_.